# How to implement custom delete in Django?

Tags: django, model

When I delete records of `table-A`, I'd like to move the rows to `table-A-history` table.

Is it suffice to override manager's `delete()` method to actually move and delete?

All the `soft delete` I've been able to find uses bool flag to indicate a soft-delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

If you override the `delete()` method then it will be called every time you delete single object:

```
my_obj.delete()
```

But this method will not called on [bulk queryset's `delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects).

```
MyModel.objects.filter(some=value).delete()
```

I suspect that you can create for this model the [custom QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) and override it's `delete()` method.

Comment: you mean when I override the queryset or manager's delete, It wouldn't affect the obj.delete(). and I'd need to override model's delete as well for it?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but AFAIK `instance.delete()` doesn't use the model's queryset.  So I think yes, you have to override both `delete()` methods.

Comment: I've been using manager method to define a method which doesn't return a queryset. (such as boolean). `delete()` seems unique in a sense, it returns none() queryset. What's the difference between the queryset method vs manager method? maybe I should ask this in a separate question..

Comment: As far as I understand there is no difference between manager methods and queryset methods.  Moreover, you can create a manager from the queryset using the `as_manager()` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#creating-manager-with-queryset-methods

Answer (score 1):

I have never actually implemented a feature such as the one you are attempting to make, but I would assume overriding a core feature may not be the best idea, especially as it may become a bit confusing for you. My suggestion would be to create a custom delete method as follows:

```
class Destination(modelsModel):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=9000)
    [...]

class ItemToMove(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=9000)
    [...same fields as "Destination" model...]

    def delete_and_move(self):
        Destination.objects.create(title=self.title, [...])
        self.delete()
        return "Object successfully deleted and moved"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

You can use this to delete a single object by typing `obj.delete_and_move()`, or  you can even run `items = ItemToMove.objects.filter(title='barney')`, and then delete via:

```
for i in items:
    i.delete_and_move()
```